# New job in a different country isn't meeting what was promised

Tags: new-job, job-description, different-countries

I took up an offer recently for a job abroad which came with a great job description.

The description included what I had already been doing but covered a greater field of responsibilities and activities. I was promised everything would be sorted for me when I started; all the hardware, software, accounts etc. would be setup for me - I checked multiple times this would be the case and was ensured it would.

I accepted the job giving two months notice and on starting I had nothing; no hardware, software or accounts. It's been over a month since starting and I'm still missing access to multiple systems - I can't even access their time-sheet system to record my hours, though fortunately I'm still being paid. But once I have access to everything, the work I will be doing doesn't even begin to cover what I had been doing previously.

Normally I'd give a job six months, see how things were going and if I wasn't happy, start looking elsewhere. However this is abroad and I'm in the process of getting ready to move here permanently - buy or rent a place and either sell all my stuff and by new stuff, or get what I have shipped. It's a costly process and will tie me to the country for at least an extra six months to a year.

I've been told it's just teething problems; it's a newly created role and I'll soon start doing the extra work which was described. But colleagues have told me it's probably going to take a few years, they've been hearing the same for some time and the systems we would be working with still don't exist.

Now I'm unsure what to do; if I stay I will have to move in soon, the company is paying for my accommodation at the moment but have told me this will only be for a couple more months. If I decide to quit I'll have to find a new job pretty quick. There is also the possibility I could leave too soon and miss out on what (on paper) is a pretty good job.

I want to give the job a fair try, but I've not had chance to due to so many issues getting started, but I will have a one-on-one with the boss next week so I'm going to have to go through this with him. He really is trying his best, but so were his predecessors who eventually had enough of trying and gave up; it's a huge company and even the smallest change takes ages.

If you were in my situation what would you be doing; what would you say to my boss and how long would you be willing to stick the job out for before you made up your mind on whether to stay or leave? Do you think being under-stimulated is a good enough reason to leave? I've been searching for work back home, have contacted a few friends to ask about work and have a few house/flats listed here that I could rent or buy if I decide to stay but I have to make up my mind soon.

Comment: Did the company provide you with relocation money/support? If so, did they have you sign an agreement to work for a certain period or you would have to pay back the money?

Comment: But one thing @mkennedy - if so - who cares?  What are they going to do? Sue him?  So what?

Comment: @Fattie: so you think it's okay to not honor your agreements, as long as you think you can get away with it ?

Comment: It seems to be totally a matter of discussion, @Hilmar.  As I understand it, on the company side, they have **utterly, totally** dishonored every single aspect of their side of the agreement.  Almost certainly the agreement would include provisions that it is void if one side totally fails to carry.  (Please note, I have no clue, whatsoever, has "really" happened: we can only discuss these QA given the facts as stated.)

Comment: {Note that if one side can completely void an agreement and - astoundingly - the other side has to carry, with no consequences, then, the obvious thing would be for the employee to just sit there and do nothing, indeed, not even turn up - and then the company would "have to" continue to pay the employee.  Of course, that's completely absurd - they wouldn't pay him for 1 minute if this happened, as the agreement would be void.}

Comment: that would be a great deal !  :)

Comment: A month after starting and you still have no hardware, software or access to systems? You don't happen to work for a national, regional or local government agency in the USA do you? ... because that's pretty normal. I've worked in the private and public sectors in the USA, and let me tell you. Sometimes I couldn't do anything for 2 months. Is this a large company with a large bureaucracy?

Answer (score 3):

**If you were in my situation what would you be doing:**

**what would you say to my boss** 
-> You need to have clear communication with your boss. He should be aware of the transformation and issues of the company and maybe has a global view of the situation and he can give you a timeframe when things will start to get better.
( if he tells you than whithin 2 years things will get better, would you accept it?).

**how long would you be willing to stick the job out for before you made up your mind on whether to stay or leave?** 
-> it depends. For a well establish company I would say that in 6 month you can have a good understanding of the company's culture. In your case ( a growing company abroad) it is more complicated because the company culture is evolving very fast depending on the recrutement and the changes of direction from the CEO than can happens. 
As the work is abroad and the company is growing, the question is : are you willing to take a risk and work in a company that can be great but only 2  years from now or do you prefer security and working the headquater of a top 500 company?

**Do you think being under-stimulated is a good enough reason to leave?**
-> Yes. But 2 month is too early too tell IMHO. some company are messy and it can takes time for things to really get organized.

**He really is trying his best, but so were his predecessors who eventually had enough of trying and gave up**
-> since how long your department was created? if more than 3 years and there is still not the basics tools for working I would consider this as a red flag.

Going Abroad to work is a definetely not for everybody, it can be very challenging but can offers great reward ( quick promotion).